# clang_complete - cc_args.py won't generate .clang_complete file

Tags: vim, clang, clang-complete

I have setup a simple project to test viability of VIM as C++ complier plus a simple makefile from a tutorial, but I can't seem to generate .clang_complete file from cc_args.py script.

Readme says I should run:

```c
make CC='~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py gcc' CXX='~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py g++' -B
```

But it won't generate .clang_complete file from makefile.

Here is my simple project.

```c
//hello.cpp
#include "hello.h"

int main(void)
{
    hello();
    return 0;
}

//hello_fn.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.h"

void hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
}

//hello.h
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H
void hello();
#endif
```

Makefile:

```c
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Ihead
DEPS = hello.h
OBJ = hello.cpp hello_fn.cpp

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hello: $(OBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

hello.h is in directory called head.

Running:

```c
make CC='.vim/bundle/clang_complete/bin/cc_args.py gcc' CXX='.vim/bundle/clang_complete/bin/cc_args.py g++' -B
```

or:

```
make CXX='.vim/bundle/clang_complete/bin/cc_args.py g++' -B
```

yields no .clang_complete file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Makefile ignores the `CC` and `CXX` environmental variables and just uses `g++` directly. Change the hello rule to

```
hello: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

And then `make CXX='.vim/bundle/clang_complete/bin/cc_args.py g++' -B` should work.

The `%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)` rule does use `CC`, but this rule is never used since your `OBJS` variable are all `.cpp` and not `.o` variables.

Comment: Will not work if one uses `cmake` since `makefile` generated by it does not respect both `CC` and `CXX`.

Comment: @Haroogan cmake respects `CC` and `CXX` environmental variables. You just have to delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file so it gets recreated.

Comment: Of course I did it, you can actually inspect `makefile` contents and see that `gcc` and `g++` invocations are hard-coded there.